# How do you catch the output of a void function that takes ostream as a parameter into a stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, cout, ostream, sstream

Let's say we have:

```
void print(std::ostream &o) {
    o << "Hello World!";
}
```

and:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << print(std::cout); // does not work
    std::string outputString = ss.str();
    std::cout << outputString << endl;
}
```

I understand this will not working because print() has type void. How would I change my code for this to work?

Solution:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    print(ss);
    std::string outputString = ss.str();
    std::cout << outputString << endl;
}
```

Comment: If "Solution" is meant to be the solution to your question , it should be posted in the Answer box instead of as part of the question

Comment: Why don't you just [return](https://godbolt.org/z/d5eh5vnd3) the stream reference?